# Color each curve with its proability to appear

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, color

I have a function f(x) which is dependent on a random parameter a.

I can define a matrix Y containing {x,f(x),P}, where P is the probability that the curve appears. I would like to plot these curves with a gradient on each curve representing its own probability.

The code :

```
f[x_, a_] := Piecewise[{{a*Sin[x]/x, 2*Pi > x > 0}}];
n = 100;
a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], n];
P = Table[N@Probability[x <= a[[i]], x \[Distributed] a], {i, 1, n}];
Y = Table[Table[{i, f[i, a[[j]]], P[[j]]}, {i, 0, 2*Pi, 0.01}], {j, 1, n}];
ListPlot[Y[[All, All, {1, 2}]],Joined->True]
```

It may be like

```
ListPlot[Y[[All, All, {1, 2}]], ColorFunction->...]
```

or

```
ListPlot[Y[[All, All, {1, 2}]], PlotStyle->Table[ColorData[...]]]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Edit: My first approach didn't work as intended, it only took the last opacity value in the table.
Here is a version with colors, albeit based on `a` rather than `P`:

```
ClearAll[f, n, a, P, Y];
f[x_, a_] := Piecewise[{{a*Sin[x]/x, 2*Pi > x > 0}}];
n = 100;
a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], n];
P = ParallelTable[
   N@Probability[x <= a[[i]], x \[Distributed] a], {i, 1, n}];
Y = ParallelTable[
   Table[{i, f[i, a[[j]]], P[[j]]}, {i, 0, 2*Pi, 0.01}], {j, 1, n}];
ListPlot[Y[[All, All, {1, 2}]], Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Hue /@ (Abs[a - 1])]
```

Returns:

[image]

Old approach: I believe different colors would be too confusing for displaying the probability with this many curves. Heres a version with different opacitylevels:

```
ClearAll[f, n, a, P, Y];
f[x_, a_] := Piecewise[{{a*Sin[x]/x, 2*Pi > x > 0}}];
n = 100;
a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], n];
P = Table[N@Probability[x <= a[[i]], x \[Distributed] a], {i, 1, n}];
Y = Table[
   Table[{i, f[i, a[[j]]], P[[j]]}, {i, 0, 2*Pi, 0.01}], {j, 1, n}];
ListPlot[Y[[All, All, {1, 2}]], Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity /@ (P*0.2)]]
```

Returns:

[image]